# Get working directory of TFS XAML Build Agents using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

My goal is to come up with a Powershell script to clean the working directory of XAML build agents.

To get the working directory of build agents I could use below C# code, which works fine.

I would like to implement the same in Powershell.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var TPC = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("CollectionURI"));

        IBuildServer buildServer = TPC.GetService<IBuildServer>();

     \\ {Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildServer}

        var buildController = buildServer.GetBuildController("ControllerName");

        var buildAgent = buildController.Agents;

        var workingFolder = string.Empty;

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (IBuildAgent agent in buildAgent)
        {
            list.Add(agent.BuildDirectory);
        }
    }
```

If it is not possible to find the Powershell equivalent I will have to consume the C# in Powershell through an exe or dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar with your C# code:

```
$url = "http://xxxx:8080/tfs/CollectionName/";
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($url);
$buildservice = $tfs.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer");
$buildcontroller = $buildservice.GetBuildController("ControllerName");
$buildagents = $buildcontroller.Agents;
foreach($buildagent in $buildagents)
{
    Write-Host $buildagent.BuildDirectory;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Kudos. Thank you.

I just had to add the below two to the script.

    `Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"`

I am looking to load the assemblies via -AssemblyName option now.